# How to write a scene were a character is falling in darkness?

Tags: creative-writing, horror, death

Hello everyone I'm having issues on writing  a scene about death. My character just died and I want to set a scene were she is falling in darkness. I'm having trouble about this . Could someone help me ? Thank you.

Comment: Please could you be more specific about what you're having trouble with? What have you tried, and which bit of it isn't working?

Comment: To help us understand your question, I'm going to ask how "She fell into the darkness" is insufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you have not supplied sufficient details to be be able to answer your questions. Rather than give you answers, I am going to pose some questions to highlight the missing details. These are largely issues of technique rather than content, but that is what this forum is all about.

What is the genre of the story? If a woman has died and is falling in darkness, the conventional wisdom is that the only thing that we would sense is the thud when the lifeless body hits bottom. But your question suggests that conventional wisdom does not hold here. Is this paranormal or some other genre that allows for a "life" after death? Is there a religious component to the story? Without the answers to these and other related questions, the possible stories number in the millions. Way too many for us to figure out what to recommend.

What is the point of view? Is the falling woman telling her story (assuming some form of afterlife) in first person? Is she telling it in near real time (present tense) or from a more distant vantage point (past tense)? Is someone else telling the story (third person past tense)? Perhaps, the person who pushed the falling woman? Perhaps, the person who failed to prevent the death and fall? In any case, can the narrator see into the thoughts and knowledge of the falling woman? The same story will read much differently when it is told as a first person, present tense story from the same events told as a third person, past tense story.

Who is this woman? Is she blameless or is she getting what she deserves? What is it about her that makes the reader want to care about her and her fate? What will we learn by reading her story? What can we learn from the changes that she goes through (or does not go through) in the story?

There are many more questions that need to be answered, but these few should give you an idea of the kind of analysis that you need to do before you can complete the story. We could guess at the answers, but this is (or will be) your story and the responsibility for answering is yours as well.

Answer (score 3):

How does she know that she is falling?  Does she feel herself go weightless?  Wind blasting her from 'below'?  What can she hear?  Does she bump into or hit anything on the way down?

If it is dark, then don't make *that* the whole scene.  Embrace her other senses, or her inner thoughts - she has just died.  Does she remember her death?  How does she react to that?  Are her mind or eyes playing tricks on her in the darkness, making phantom visions blink into and out of existence in the corner of her eye?